# "The current backend id,DB2UDBNT_V91_1, does not have equivalent deployed code in the jar." error while WAS 8.5 server startup

Tags: eclipse, db2, websphere

we are migrating our project from Websphere 6.1 to 8.5 and java from 1.5 to 1.7. While starting the server, we are getting this error. Not sure of the reason, could someone help me. Its been 2 days now :( We are using DB2.

```
[3/3/16 12:45:26:555 IST] 00000049 SharedEJBRunt I   WSVR0057I: EJB jar started: BDSService.jar
[3/3/16 12:45:26:609 IST] 00000049 SharedEJBRunt I   WSVR0037I: Starting EJB jar: batchejb.jar
[3/3/16 12:45:26:614 IST] 00000049 WASNameSpaceB I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.s1.arch.batch.core.BatchThreadProcessorServiceHome interface of the BatchService enterprise bean in the batchejb.jar module of the epj2ee application.  The binding location is: ejb/com/s1/arch/batch/BatchService
[3/3/16 12:45:26:617 IST] 00000049 AbstractEJBRu I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.s1.arch.batch.core.BatchThreadProcessorServiceHome interface of the BatchService enterprise bean in the batchejb.jar module of the epj2ee application.  The binding location is: java:global/epj2ee/batchejb/BatchService!com.s1.arch.batch.core.BatchThreadProcessorServiceHome
[3/3/16 12:45:26:621 IST] 00000049 SharedEJBRunt I   WSVR0057I: EJB jar started: batchejb.jar
[3/3/16 12:45:26:672 IST] 00000049 SharedEJBRunt I   WSVR0037I: Starting EJB jar: coreejb.jar
[3/3/16 12:45:26:686 IST] 00000049 PMModuleCooki E   PMGR1010E: The current backend id,DB2UDBNT_V91_1, does not have equivalent deployed code in the jar.
[3/3/16 12:45:26:686 IST] 00000049 PMModuleCooki E   PMGR0000E: Call stack:
com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.utilpm.PersistenceManagerException: PMGR1010E: The current backend id,DB2UDBNT_V91_1, does not have equivalent deployed code in the jar.
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.ConcreteBeanClassExtensionImpl.createPMException(ConcreteBeanClassExtensionImpl.java:340)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.PMModuleCookieImpl.getBindingName(PMModuleCookieImpl.java:460)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.PMModuleCookieImpl.beanInstall(PMModuleCookieImpl.java:365)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.PersistenceManagerImpl.beanInstall(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASEJBRuntimeImpl.addHome(WASEJBRuntimeImpl.java:1686)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.startModule(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:336)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3576)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2182)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)

[3/3/16 12:45:26:688 IST] 00000049 AbstractEJBRu E   CNTR0035E: EJB container caught javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.utilpm.PersistenceManagerException: PMGR1010E: The current backend id,DB2UDBNT_V91_1, does not have equivalent deployed code in the jar.
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.PMModuleCookieImpl.getBindingName(PMModuleCookieImpl.java:460)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.PMModuleCookieImpl.beanInstall(PMModuleCookieImpl.java:365)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.PersistenceManagerImpl.beanInstall(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASEJBRuntimeImpl.addHome(WASEJBRuntimeImpl.java:1686)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.startModule(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:336)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3576)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2182)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.utilpm.PersistenceManagerException: PMGR1010E: The current backend id,DB2UDBNT_V91_1, does not have equivalent deployed code in the jar.
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.ConcreteBeanClassExtensionImpl.createPMException(ConcreteBeanClassExtensionImpl.java:340)
    ... 20 more
 and is throwing com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerException: ; nested exception is: 
    javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.utilpm.PersistenceManagerException: PMGR1010E: The current backend id,DB2UDBNT_V91_1, does not have equivalent deployed code in the jar..
```

Comment: I'm having this issue to. First time I clone and compile my code it runs fine, but when I run a second time I get this error. I think my issue has to do with intellij not deploying the same version to websphere 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using CMP EJB. During deployment you have to select backend_ID for generated EJB code. You are currently selecting DB2UDBNT_V91_1, but looks like you dont have code generated for that.
You either have to select correct backendID, or check `Deploy EJB` option during installation.

First check if in your EJB module, you have that backendID folder. I don't remember in which exact subfolder it should be, but you should have `backends` subfolder with generated files (CMPs are dead technology, I didn't use it for some time).

You may have folder with different backend name or no folder. You may need to generate mapping for CMPs and generate code once again, if your database is changing. You should be able to recreate mapping and generate code from Rational Application Developer tool.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.But I see that I have a folder named 'DB2UDBNT_V91_1'in backends folder as you mentioned. So. I'm clueless about the rootcause for this error. Suggest me what is this backendID and its purpose so that I can explore more on this. Thanks.

Comment: @chaitupnvs How are you migrating the application? Are you trying just to run EAR exported from 6.1 server to install on 8.5? Or are you building EAR from the scratch from sources? Did you try that "Deploy EJB" option during installation?

Comment: ,its from scratch.Anyway,my issue got resolved.'ibm_pmbab.properties' file got missed in backends folder in META_INF and after adding that, issue got resolved.Thanks.