# Websphere start throws derby exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-8

When I try to start WAS 8.5.5 I see the below exception. There is nothing related to derby in my application. If I start the server without any application then I don't receive this exception. Unfortunately I see it when I deploy.

```
ContainerHelp E   WSVR0501E: Error creating component com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl@33cf2ee9
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerException: ; nested exception is: 
    javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.utilpm.PersistenceManagerException: PMGR1010E: The current backend id,DERBY_V100_1, does not have equivalent deployed code in the jar.
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:322)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:539)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationServerImpl.start(ApplicationServerImpl.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:539)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:523)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:310)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:223)
    ...
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:150)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerException: ; nested exception is: 
    javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.utilpm.PersistenceManagerException: PMGR1010E: The current backend id,DERBY_V100_1, does not have equivalent deployed code in the jar.
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:746)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.startModule(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:336)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3576)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    ...
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerException: ; nested exception is: 
    javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.utilpm.PersistenceManagerException: PMGR1010E: The current backend id,DERBY_V100_1, does not have equivalent deployed code in the jar.
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:643)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.utilpm.PersistenceManagerException: PMGR1010E: The current backend id,DERBY_V100_1, does not have equivalent deployed code in the jar.
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.PMModuleCookieImpl.getBindingName(PMModuleCookieImpl.java:460)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.PMModuleCookieImpl.beanInstall(PMModuleCookieImpl.java:365)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.PersistenceManagerImpl.beanInstall(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASEJBRuntimeImpl.addHome(WASEJBRuntimeImpl.java:1686)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:639)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.utilpm.PersistenceManagerException: PMGR1010E: The current backend id,DERBY_V100_1, does not have equivalent deployed code in the jar.
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.ConcreteBeanClassExtensionImpl.createPMException(ConcreteBeanClassExtensionImpl.java:340)
    ... 20 more
```

Kindly suggest how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this was answered here: ["The current backend id,DB2UDBNT_V91_1, does not have equivalent deployed code in the jar." error while WAS 8.5 server startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767505/the-current-backend-id-db2udbnt-v91-1-does-not-have-equivalent-deployed-code-i)

> Anyway,my issue got resolved.'ibm_pmbab.properties' file got missed in backends folder in META_INF and after adding that, issue got resolved.Thanks.

Comment: where can I get this file because i don't find it in my WAS installation and is there any configuration I need to do here ?

Comment: [This link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21425972) makes it look like it should be generated by EJBDeploy

Comment: Thanks for reply ... Am quite new to WAS and in my previous installation of WAS 7 there was no such folder or file. Also I don't have a separate EJB component so that I can deploy it explicitly. So with standard deployment this file should have been generated ? and now since its not what steps I should take to fix it.